# Proving that a certain function $f : \mathbb{C}\backslash\{0\}\to \mathbb{C}\backslash\{0\}$ does not exists

Tags: complex-analysis, solution-verification

I'd like to show that there is no function $f: \mathbb{C}\backslash\{0\}\to  \mathbb{C}\backslash\{0\}$ with the following properties: $f(z)f(w) = f(zw)$ and $(f(z))^n = z, n \geq 2$.

For $n = 2$, it is quite easy to show. Assuming $f$ exists, then we have $1 = (f(1))^2 = f(1)f(1) = f(1^2) = f(1)$. Also, $-1 = (f(-1))^2 = f((-1)^2) = f(1)$. This is a contradiction.

For $n > 3$ I don't know how to prove it. I was thinking of using $z \in \mathbb{C}\backslash\{0\}$ such that $z^n = 1$. Then
$$f(1) = f(1^n) = (f(1))^n = 1 $$
and
$$e^{i2\pi/n} = (f(e^{i2\pi/n}))^n = f((e^{i2\pi/n})^n) = f(e^{i2\pi}) = f(1).$$
But $1 \neq e^{i2\pi/n}$ for $n > 3$. So a contradiction. Is this proof correct?

Comment: What are your doubts about your proof?

Comment: @FormulaWriter Can I use the choice $z = e^{i2\pi/n}$? Also, I am not sure whether $ 1 \neq e^{i2\pi/n}$ is true as well, to be honest. I think if these doubts are cleared, then the proof must be correct, right?

Comment: You can use $z = e^{i2\pi/n}$ and also $1 \neq e^{i2\pi/n}$ holds for natural $n>1$. The proof is correct.

Comment: The only mistake is that you wrote $n>3$ instead of $n\geq 3$. Moreover, the case $n=2$ behaves just as the case $n\geq 3$, therefore there is no need to treat the two cases separately. Despite this, your proof is quite elegant